# How to get a parental venue using a child venue

Tags: foursquare

Is there any way to get a parental venue using a  child venue? For example, there's a Starbucks in an airport. I want to get the airport instead of the Starbucks. The Foursquare App has the section called "Other places inside xxx", so I thought there's a way to get it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call the [venue details](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) API there will be a `parent` object in the response. I did a test with an airport terminal and saw.

`GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4c1fa175eac020a1c3614bc2`

```
      "parent": {
        "id": "41059b00f964a520850b1fe3",
        "name": "San Francisco International Airport (SFO) (San Francisco International Airport)",
        "contact": {
          "phone": "6508218211",
          "formattedPhone": "(650) 821-8211",
          "twitter": "flysfo",
          "instagram": "flysfo",
          "facebookUsername": "flySFO",
          "facebookName": "San Francisco International Airport (SFO)"
      }
```